# stackoverflow when using two components Dagger2

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow, dagger-2

I have two Components for Dagger :

```
@GithubListActivityScope
@Component(modules = { GithubListActivityModule.class, GlideActivityModule.class })
public interface GithubListActivityComponent {

GithubUserListAdapter githubUserListAdapter ( );
//RequestManager requestManager();
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager();

}
```

**Note : I have tried commenting and uncommenting** `RequestManager requestManager();`in `GithubListActivityComponent`

I have another Component like this :

```
@Component(modules = { GithubApiServiceModule.class, GlideModule.class })
public interface GithubAppListComponent {

RequestManager getGlideRequestManager ( );

GithubAPIService getGitHubApiService ( );
}
```

**Problem :** -> When **I delete** the **class file** of `GithubListActivityComponent` or **delete/comment  the @Component Annotation** the app runs fine **BUT** when I try building without deleting  or commenting the @Component Annotation the file  I get the following error :

> Error:(7, 66) error: cannot find symbol class
>   DaggerGithubAppListComponent
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    java.lang.StackOverflowError

P.S. Oracle Jdk version -> 1.8.0_121

Comment: Sorry my mistake .... what annotation processor are you using?

Comment: As far I can process your question, I have not used any custom, It must be the default Java Annotation processor ... Sorry if I didn't answer to the point.

Comment: What is the relationship between `GithubListActivityComponent` and `GithubAppListComponent`? It sounds like the first should probably be a subcomponent of the second.

Comment: one is application level component another is activity level

Comment: Maybe you have a circular dependency?

Comment: My  included GithubListActivityModule.class in  GlideActivityModule.class and  GlideActivityModule.class in GithubListActivityModule.class , that is a circular dependency right ?

Comment: I have removed inclusion of  GlideActivityModule.class from GithubListActivityModule , altered some access modifier now i can successfully create the component object in activity ... But I am getting into this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184165/dagger-2-does-not-inject-my-object-but-can-be-obtained-from-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove Circular Dependency** (**A** module **should not include B** Module **if B** Module **includes A** )

**How I solved my problem :** the providers(Methods with **@Provide**) that were on **GithubListActivityModule** **and depended** on **GlideActivityModule**, I **moved** them into **GlideActivityModule** to remove the dependency.