# Dagger 2 does not inject my Object but can be obtained from component

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have my component like

```
@GithubListActivityScope
@Component(modules = { GithubListActivityModule.class,GlideActivityModule.class })
public interface GithubListActivityComponent {

GithubUserListAdapter githubUserListAdapter ( );
RequestManager requestManager();
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager();

}
```

And I have a module like this :

```
@Module
public class GithubListActivityModule {
private final Activity githubListActivity;


public GithubListActivityModule ( Activity activity ) {
    this.githubListActivity = activity;

}

@Provides
@GithubListActivityScope
Activity activity ( ) {
    return this.githubListActivity;
}

@Provides
@GithubListActivityScope
public LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager(Activity activity){
    return  new LinearLayoutManager ( activity );
}
}
```

Problem :
I have treid to inject LinearLayout manager like this :

```
@GithubListActivityScope
@Inject
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
```

While my Component is built like this :

```
githubListActivityComponent = DaggerGithubListActivityComponent.builder ()
            .githubListActivityModule ( new GithubListActivityModule ( this ) )
            .build ();
```

my Linear Layout manager does not get instantiated. But when I manually do

```
 linearLayoutManager = githubListActivityComponent.linearLayoutManager ();
```

It works fine. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everywhere that I am passing `Activity` , I should **pass exactly** **the same** **class  Name (not its parent)**  So once edited every parameters and return types that were `"Activity"` into `"GithubListActivity"` and then added

```
void inject( GithubListActivity activity);
```

inside the `component class`

then injected `"GithubListActivity"` 
like this :

```
DaggerGithubListActivityComponent.builder ()
            .githubListActivityModule ( new GithubListActivityModule ( this ) )
            .build ().inject ( this );
```

Then the codes worked for me ..

**Lesson :

1. Define inject method and Inject the current Activity**

**2. Use exactly the same type of object (not the parent ) in this case use "GithubListActivity"  instead of just activity.**

Comment: does it mean we will define many interface methods with different activity names?

Comment: If we do not do other work around this idea then yes we have to inject every activities. But some other cool guy out there in the internet might have solution for that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Dagger 2 does not inject fields automatically. It can also not inject private fields. If you want to use field injection you have to define a method in your @Component interface which takes the instance into which you want to inject as parameter (From  - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html#special-treatment-of-fields-in-dagger)

Suppose you have a fragment or Activity into which you want to inject these dependencies, then do something like this -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((YouApplicationClass) getActivity().getApplication()).getmComponent().inject(this);
}
```

Let your Application class be like this  -

```
public class YourApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static final String TAG = v.class.getSimpleName();

    private YourComponent mComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mComponent = DaggerYoutComponent.builder()
                .yourModule(new YourModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public YourComponent getmComponent() {
        return mComponent;
    }

   .... lots of other code
}
```

and your component class be something like this -

```
//@Singleton
@Component(modules = {YourModule.class})
public interface YourComponent {

    void inject(Fragment yourFragment); //the parameter can be any class who is invoking this method i.e. Passing the reference to itself

   ..lots of other code
}
```